# In what order will multiple pyspark program get executed on a spark cluster

Tags: pyspark

If I submit multiple python (pyspark) files to a spark submit command, in which order will they get executed?

For Java, there is a `main` method which will get executed first and the rest of the classes will get executed in the order their objects/methdos are created/invoked.

But python (and also scala) allows the whole REPL style syntax whereby one is allowed to type commands in an 'open code' fashion, i.e outside method blocks.

So when a whole bunch of this REPL statements get submitted to the spark cluster, in what order will they execute?

Comment: by "multiple python files", do you mean via `--py-files`?

Comment: Correct. I am submitting a py package with 5 files, all of them have 'open code'. If executing manually on local, i know in which order to call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/configuration.html

> `spark.submit.pyFiles` (which is `--py-files`): Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps. Globs are allowed.

So the python files which are added by `--py-files` meant to be libraries, or modules, or packages, not for runnable scripts. You will need to create a `main.py` or something similar, then import the other 5 files and trigger in any order you want `spark-submit --py-files five-files.zip main.py`